# Amplitube 4 not receiving MIDI signals

Tags: midi, behringer

I'm trying to use my MIDI controller to operate the looper in the Amplitube 4 standalone app (on Windows 10 Pro). My controller is a Behringer FCB1010, connected to a Behringer UMC404HD. I have the UMC404HD selected as the MIDI input in Amplitube's Audio MIDI setup.

I have clicked on MIDI...MIDI Control...Control Change...Global...LOOP1...Learn, but the "Waiting for MIDI input" message doesn't go away when I tap any of the 5 pedals on the FCB1010 (which are programmed to send CC91-CC95 respectively).

I have checked the MIDI controller using Midi-Ox and the controller is sending all of the expected codes. The controller also works fine with Reaper. So there isn't a hardware or USB connectivity problem.

Any idea why I can't get Amplitube to detect the MIDI signal input?

EDIT: I made a partial breakthrough....my MIDI controller was sending PC messages rather than CC messages. When I reconfigured it to send CC messages they were finally recognised. However...

While I have "taught" Amplitube the MIDI CC codes for LOOP1-4 and Next/Prev, only the Looper is responding when I send the MIDI signals. I can't get Next/Prev to work. The correct MIDI codes are definitely being sent, but I can't get them to trigger the Next/Prev actions. The red light flashes when I hit the button on the MIDI controller, and sometimes I see the number 000 flash up in the field next to the Preset name at the top, but nothing else happens.

Any ideas??